# Convert sparse item-item similarity matrix to smaller data structure

Tags: python, dictionary, linked-list

I have a 8,000 x 8,000 item-item similarity matrix that is very sparse. The idea is for all 8,000 products, I would create a Linked List (or something similar) where the flow would be

Key-> Node_1-> Node_2-> etc.

"Key" would, for example, be Product "B" and Node_1 would be Product "A" and also have the similarity that exists between A and B (0 <= similarity <= 1). Products with similarity of 0 would not be included.

Is there a better way to accomplish this other than creating a struct and then having a linked list of structs? I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: I think sparse matrix is what you are looking for http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html

Comment: What does Node2 indicate?

Comment: Node2 indicates the same thing as Node1. My current solution is to create a dictionary where the product name is the key and a list of objects is the value... What do you think?